# aspnetcore2.0 azure web app deployment enable organizational authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, adal

I'm migrating a web app from aspnetcore1.0 in VS2015 to aspnetcore2.0 using VS1017.

I'm using azure active directory and jwt bearer authentication to protect my rest endpoints consumed by an angularjs client within the same project

everything works fine while debugging in my machine, but when I deploy it to azure I get this error when making a request

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: clientSecret

Taking a look using kudu in the azure portal there are no environmental variables for azuread settings, nor an evironmental variable for the client secrets as they used to be in the netcore1.0 case. In VS2015 I got the checkbox 'Enable organizational authentication' when publishing the app but it's not the case in VS2017, I'm guessing it has something to do with the env variables being created in the deployment process to azure.

My question is what is the best practice when deploying to azure an aspnetcoreapp2.0 from VS2017 with this type authentication, and how to manage the app settings and client secrets for aad auth in a production environment?

Libs used in the aspnetcore2.0 VS1017 project:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.1.0-preview1-26771"
"Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" Version="2.1.1"
"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="3.16.0"
```

aspnetcore1.0 VS105 Environmental variables:

[image]

These are missing when deployed from VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.net Core 1.0 , when developing web app enable organizational authentication , Visual Studio will create Azure AD configurations in `appsettings.json`

```
  "Authentication": {
    "AzureAd": {
      "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
      "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Domain": "testnanyu.onmicrosoft.com",
      "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
```

Then if overriding nested keys in Azure App Services (through environment variables) , you can define a variable using the full path `Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId` as name .

But in Asp.net Core 2.0 , Visual Studio will create Azure AD configurations like :

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "testnanyu.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

The structure is changed . So if overriding nested keys in Azure App Services (through environment variables) , you can define a variable in portal like `AzureAd:ClientId` . With kudu , it shows `APPSETTING_AzureAd:ClientId` as environment variable .

Comment: Ended up overriding nested keys in Azure App Services as you suggested and it worked just fine, thanks by the way. Anyway it feels like a step back that it doesn't get done automatically during deployment from visual studio like previous aspnetcore versions, probably it will in further vs updates.

Comment: The fact that they moved the configuration code out from startup.cs confused me a little bit as I thought the cause of this issue was that I was missing something in this matter. Here's a good article on the tructural changes of aspnetcore2.0 for anyone who's interested https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-2-0-preview-1